# why do we not use {{ }} while removing hardcoded urls in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

```
<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

here we use {{ }} tag as question.id is a variable but,

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

when we remove the hardcoded url from our template why we do not use {{ }} around the question.id?

Answer (score 0):

`{% %}` denotes a template tag and anything inside are, kind of, treated as python code. Look at it as a kind of **escape**. Whereas `{{ }}` escapes variables themselves so you can use the values.

See the docs for more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language